# Apache www HTTPS Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all traffic from all forms of my url to go to
https without the www

I found this code on another post and it works perfect for https, but it adds www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I tried removing the www from the first RewriteRule above, but it still redirects to www

Any ideas what I can change to get the redirect to go https without the www

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess for redirects is now an outdated way to redirect requests like this, [according to apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect). Instead, you should use `Redirect` in your vhost file:

`Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"`

Comment: Do you care to explain this in more detail? What exactly is a vhost file? I am using 1and1 shared hosting if that helps any. They didn't give me this exact code from above, but gave me this                                               RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [L,R=301]

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that you had access to the apache configuration files. In the case that you don't, you are left having to do it based on .htaccess redirects. Please refer to @Lag 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for two reasons.

1. In your first set of rules, you're redirecting to `www`, so just change that to this:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```
2. Your second set of rules is actually checking if `www` is not on, and if it isn't then to force `www`. Change that the rule to the following:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```

So the above now checks to see if `www` is on - if it is then it will remove it.

You can however combine these two rules instead of having them seperate:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: I made the changes in your steps 1 and 2 and found one case when it doesn't redirect, but instead throws an error "The page isn’t redirecting properly" and that is when the url is entered as https www

Comment: I've made a slight edit to the code above. Try it now. Also, do you have anything else in your `.htaccess`, or is this it?

Comment: How can I add Line Breaks when making a comment?    I also have this <ifModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
 </ifModule>

Comment: Do you care to post the original code, so that I can compare the two. I haven't had a chance to try this out, but hopefully I can this evening.

Comment: In the original all I did was change `.*` to `^(.*)$` in all instances of it.

Comment: I tried the new code and it changes the URL correctly, but then the browser throws an error that says The page isn’t redirecting properly.